# Detect mouse down outside NSViewController in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, nsview, nsviewcontroller

How can I detect mouse down events outside an `NSViewController` in swift ? I haven't found any examples in swift yet ...

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask` to record any event happening outside of your app.

Put this into `AppDelegate` after `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.LeftMouseDownMask, handler: {(event: NSEvent) in

// Do what you have to do here

})
```

Comment: exactly what I needed ! Thank you

Comment: You should use local not global.

Comment: Global is for events outside the window whereas local is for events within the app/window right ?